# Interleave multiple streams

Tags: scala, functional-programming, fs2

I have a list of streams `List[Stream[_]]`, size of list is known at the beginning of function, size of each stream equals `n` or `n+1`. I'd like to obtain interleave stream
e.g.

```
def myMagicFold[A](s: List[Stream[A]]): Stream[A]

val streams = List(Stream(1,1,1),Stream(2,2,2),Stream(3,3),Stream(4,4)) 

val result = myMagicFold(streams)

//result = Stream(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2)
```

I'm using `fs2.Stream`. My first take:

```
val result = streams.fold(fs2.Stream.empty){
   case (s1, s2) => s1.interleaveAll(s2)
}

// result = Stream(1, 4, 3, 4, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2)
```

I'm looking for a solution based on basic operations (`map`, `fold`,...)

Comment: Not really, as i mentiond at the end of the queation i'm looking for a generic solution

Comment: Anyways, serious question about the problem. You said the number of Streams in the list is known before calling the function. That means at compile time? Like it may be simpler to create overloaded versions of the function for 2 to N streams, if N is always going to be a small number.

Comment: unfortunately it isn't known at compile time, moreover N might be big

Comment: After thinking for a while, I doubt this can be done. At least not in generically _(it may be possible tough, I do not know too many things)_. I think you may write a custom `fs2.Pull`, but that would be far from general and it still seems very hard to do. Nevertheless, I would recommend you to also ask the [fs2 **gitter** channel](https://gitter.im/functional-streams-for-scala/fs2) if this is possible to do in anyway, they will know how. - PS: If you solve this, remember you can answer your own questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your initial guess was good, however `interleaveAll` flattens too soon, so that's why you don't get expected order. 
Here's the code that should do what you try to achieve:

```scala
  def zipAll[F[_], A](streams: List[Stream[F, A]]): Stream[F, A] =
    streams
      .foldLeft[Stream[F, List[Option[A]]]](Stream.empty) { (acc, s) =>
        zipStreams(acc, s)
      }
      .flatMap(l => Stream.emits(l.reverse.flatten))

  def zipStreams[F[_], A](s1: Stream[F, List[Option[A]]], s2: Stream[F, A]): Stream[F, List[Option[A]]] =
    s1.zipAllWith(s2.map(Option(_)))(Nil, Option.empty[A]) { case (acc, a) => a :: acc }
```

In this case, you're adding n-th element of each stream into the list and then convert to the `Stream` which is later flattened to the result stream.
Since `fs2.Stream` is pull-based you only have one list in memory at a time.

Comment: That's exactly what I've been looking for, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an attempt, it works as expected...

```
import cats.effect.IO
import cats.implicits._
import fs2.Stream

def myMagicFold[A](streams: List[Stream[IO, A]]): Stream[IO, A] =
  Stream.unfoldEval(streams) { streams =>
    streams.traverse { stream =>
      stream.head.compile.last
    } map { list =>
      list.sequence.map { chunk =>
        Stream.emits(chunk) -> list.map(_.tail)
      }
    }
  }.flatten
```

However, this is far from a good solution, it is extremely inefficient, since it reevaluates each **Stream** on each step.
You can confirm that with this code:

```
def stream(name: String, n: Int, value: Int): Stream[IO, Int] =
  Stream
    .range(start = 0, stopExclusive = n)
    .evalMap { i =>
      IO {
        println(s"${name} - ${i}")
        value
      }
    }
    
val list = List(stream("A", 3, 1), stream("B", 2, 2), stream("C", 3, 3))
myMagicFold(list).compile.toList.unsafeRunAsync(println)
```

Which will print

> A - 0
> B - 0
> C - 0
> A - 0
> A - 1
> B - 0
> B - 1
> C - 0
> C - 1
> A - 0
> A - 1
> A - 2
> B - 0
> B - 1
> C - 0
> C - 1
> C - 2
>
> Right(List(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3))

I am pretty sure this can be fixed using **Pulls**, but I do not have any experience with that.

Comment: Thanks for your time, currently I'm working on a solution based on Pulls. I'll post my solution as soon as I make it with immutable state

Answer (score 0):

Just to iterate over the accepted solution, the below is basically the same, but **it does not use `List`s internally, only `Stream`s** (plus it saves that final `reverse` on each of the `List`s).

The only thing that needs to be known eagerly remains the number of `Stream`s to be interleaved (hence the `streams: List[Stream[F, A]]`):

```
def interleaveAll[F[_], A](streams: List[Stream[F, A]]): Stream[F, A] =
    streams
      .foldLeft[Stream[F, Stream[F, Option[A]]]](Stream.empty) { (acc, s) =>
        interleaveStreams(acc, s)
      }
      .flatMap(l => l.unNone)

private def interleaveStreams[F[_], A](
    s1: Stream[F, Stream[F, Option[A]]],
    s2: Stream[F, A],
  ): Stream[F, Stream[F, Option[A]]] =
    s1.zipAllWith(s2.map(Option(_)))(Stream.empty, Option.empty[A]) { case (acc, a) => acc ++ Stream(a) }
```